# Android client FirebaseApp initialization error

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had GCM implemented and I am trying to import GCM to FCM now. I dont want to use google-services.json because I want to use different google projects for different environments(Dev, Stag, Prod).

I tried to initialize the app via this code below

```
 FirebaseOptions.Builder options=new FirebaseOptions.Builder();
       options.setGcmSenderId("<<project id>>"); 
       options.setApplicationId("<<Project name>>"); 
       FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(),options.build(),"MyTestFCM");
       String refreshedToken= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(firebaseApp).getToken();
```

I keep getting exception on Firebase App initialization

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. Available app names: MyTestFCM

If I remove the app name then i dont get a token back, then when I re-run the application I get a token. I have tried to execute the above piece of code from Mainactivity and Application class. In both places I get the same error.

So my question is how do I initialize Firebase application without using google-services.json

Thanks,
P

Comment: Please have a look at this discussion, where it eventually describes how you can use multiple google-services files for different build variants. https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out that you need to use google-services.json for FCM, and to handle multiple build variants situation,

1. Generate respective google-services.json from the firebase console for the different build variants.
2. Download the google-services.json
3. In your project create folders for the variants, for example if you want release build, create a folder with name "release" and place the google-services.json in it.

When the app builds, depending upon the build variant it looks for google-services.json in the respective folder and picks up the project details from it.

More details can be found on this thread
[google services issues 54](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54)

Thanks Arthur Thompson

Answer (score 1):

Firebase SDK requires to have a "default" project configured via `google-services.json`

Once you have that you can register FCM sdk with other sender-id using the `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(context).getToken(...)`

But please note that the most recent FCM features (auto-retry of the registration, topic subscriptions) only work with the default project.

Comment: but I want to use different projects for different release types. how do I manage that if i have to use only one google-services.json

Comment: you should be able to do it with some additional configuration in the gradle file.

Comment: Yup once you have defined your different build types in your gradle files, you can then place the corresponding google-services file in the appropriate directory and the plugin will look there for the file before defaulting to the app directory. have a look at this github issue where this is resolved: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54

Comment: Is there any documentation that explains exactly what features are not available if the FCM isn't the default project?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked to make sure to set your FIREBASE_URL to the right string?  Also did you make sure to have the appropriate app setup config?

Last time this happened, I needed to set up my Android App Configs.
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592

Afterwards, you can follow this setup.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: The thing is I dont want to use the App configs, I want to use different project ids for different release types so I cannot use the same google-service.json file. That is why I am trying to initiate the FirebaseApp explicitly with the project id. When I use the google-services.json I am able to receive notifications without any issues.

Comment: If that is the case, you can point to different google-service-prod.json or google-service-dev.json based on what environment you are in. Have you tried that?

Comment: In that case how do i make the code point to different flavors of  google-services.json

Answer (score 0):

Please do double check, you added

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' 
at the bottom of app's gradle file and then clean and rebuild the project