# Switching FCM configuration programmatically on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

The problem is following: we have an application with two backends - dev and prod. Each one contains different set of users. A developer can switch between them with some known to him actions in app on the fly. So for fcm we created two projects - one for dev environment and another for prod environment. On iOS we can switch between as following:

```
if([FIRApp defaultApp] != nil){

    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
    [[FIRApp defaultApp]deleteApp:^(BOOL success){

        FIROptions* firebaseOptions = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:firebaseConfigPath];
        [FIRApp configureWithOptions:firebaseOptions];

    }];

}
else{

    FIROptions* firebaseOptions = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:firebaseConfigPath];
    [FIRApp configureWithOptions:firebaseOptions];

}
```

`firebaseConfigPath` is chosen for corresponding environment.

How to implement the same on Android?
Thanks

Comment: Hmm. Are you possibly pertaining to having different flavors? See these posts -- http://stackoverflow.com/q/30772201/4625829, http://stackoverflow.com/q/37463092/4625829, http://stackoverflow.com/q/38132763/4625829

Comment: Will be those flavors inside one apk? And how to switch between them programmatically?